# Prometheus count frequency distinct values of gauge

Tags: statistics, monitoring, prometheus, grafana

`wmi_cpu_core_frequency_mhz` is a gauge that returns some unique values {a,b,c...} for label=core with values(p,q,r,s)

I want to get break down of count of each gauge value a,b,c for each label p,q,r,s

Something looking like this

```
| core | count(a) | count(b) | count(c) |...
+------+----------+----------+----------+
| p    | 10       | 35       | 5        |...
+------+----------+----------+----------+
| q    | 15       | 15       | 20       |...
+------+----------+----------+----------+
| r    | 2        | 13       | 35       |...
+------+----------+----------+----------+
| s    | 10       | 10       | 30       |...
+------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Any idea how to tackle this, or where should I start from.

Comment: You want to count the number of occurrences of a value over time ?

Comment: Yes, even though it's a gauge, It returns some handful of distinct values, I want a breakdown on how frequent is each value is.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `count_values` here, so your query would be something like `count_values (p,q,r,s) ("core", wmi_cpu_core_frequency_mhz)`.

You won't get a 2d table with this, but you should get the data you're after, at least.